# Fresh PG install on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, installation, vps

I am setting up a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server to host my new site on and having trouble setting up postgres.

I installed it fine but when I try to access it using `psql` I get:

> psql: FATAL:  role "demo" does not exist

A few quick questions:

1. Has installing postgres create an standard ubuntu user account?
2. How do I create a new postgres account, I have tried `createuser` but get the following:

   demo@dubbo:~$ createuser
   Enter name of role to add: demopg
   Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
   createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "demo" does not exist

I guess that once I have a postgres user I should then be able to create a db for my application to use.

Comment: I found this in another question: sudo -u postgres psql postgres and that let me in but can someone explain what that is doing?

Comment: Why has this been closed? Its a perfectly reasonable question and someone has posted a perfectly sensible answer below. Nothing wrong. It's very surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps I use to install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu for development (I'm using PostreSQL with Rails):

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

We need libpq-dev to be able to install the Ruby pg gem. After the setup completes, 
then run the following commands:

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser demo
$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

The first command creates a user that matches your user name. The second command creates a user for your application to use--this is what you will normally login to psql with. The third command will bring you directly into the psql console, and will open up the postgres database. It's just the database corresponding to the postgres user, which for some reason is necessary when installing PostgreSQL.

Once in the psql prompt, type the following command:

```
postgres=# \password demo
```

Set the password for your user.  Once it returns you to the prompt, type "\q" to exit the psql prompt.

Now you'll be back in your terminal, and you can then create a database for your application.

```
$ createdb your_db_name
```

Now, you need to change the postgresql.conf file to make PostgreSQL listen on at least localhost. If you have a setup where you want to listen on an external IP or something, change this line to either the IP or just '*'.

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf:
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

Then, in pg_hba.conf, make sure you've got this:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf:
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               md5
```

Otherwise you'll probably get an error when trying to login from your Rails app. After this, all you've got to do is simply start PostgreSQL using this command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

And you're set to go!  Start psql with:

```
$ psql -U demo
```

You will be prompted for the password you set.  You can connect to the database you created with:

```
# \c your_db_name
```

Good luck!

Comment: PG on Ubuntu listens by default on localhost so that doesn't need to be changed. As to the change to `pg_hba.conf` it's not clear what you'd think it's necessary. The default `peer` method is generally a better choice for local connections (note that `local` differs from `localhost` for postgres)

Comment: I'm trying to sign in to psql as my newly created user demopg with the following: psql -u demopg but get /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/psql: invalid option -- 'u'
Try "psql --help" for more information.    Any thoughts?

Comment: Uppercase U fails too. Same error

Comment: Any thoughts on this?